# using zip and generator, how can I get a batch data

Tags: iterator, zip, generator

simple example code is.

```
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[95, 50, 10, 5, 4], 
                    [85, 5, 100, 40, 3], 
                    [75, 50, 10, 30, 1],
                    [65, 50, 1, 20, 42],
                    [55, 500, 10, 10, 3],
                    [45, 50, 10, 110, 40]], dtype=np.float32) # training data

y_train = np.array([1,1,0,0,1,0]) # label 

train_data= list(zip(x_train, y_train)) # zip both data and lable

def batch_iter(data): # I make simple generator
    for i in range(len(data)) :
        yield data[i:i+1]

batches = batch_iter(train_data)

for i in range(len(x_train)):
    x, y = batches  # error happend   too many values to unpack (expected 2)
    x, y = zip(*batches) # error happend  not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

How can I take each train data and label for each iteration??

thanks.

Comment: when I do x, y = next(batches),  still same error,
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the  code like this, its working well.
I need to study generator and numpy.
please add your answer.
thanks

```
x_train = np.array([[95, 50, 10, 5, 4], 
                    [85, 5, 100, 40, 3], 
                    [75, 50, 10, 30, 1],
                    [65, 50, 1, 20, 42],
                    [55, 500, 10, 10, 3],
                    [45, 50, 10, 110, 40]], dtype=np.float32)

y_train = np.array([1,1,0,0,1,0])

train_data= list(zip(x_train, y_train))

def batch_iter(data):
  data = np.array(data)
  for i in range(len(data)) :
    yield data[i:i+1]

batches = batch_iter(train_data)

x, y = zip(*next(batches))
```